# How to insert ComboBox item into ListBox? [winforms]

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

The question is very simple,
How to insert ComboBox selected item into ListBox using c#?

I have tried with this:

```
listbox.Items.Add(combobox.SelectedItem);
```

and some other permutations but it always displays System.Data.DataRowView or something like that..

EDIT: roblem was coused by this 2

```
lbList.DisplayMember = "hm";
lbList.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: It should work, if you check&exclude null first.

Comment: It works but displays string "Systm.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: Which would have been very valuable info to include in your question :-{

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define "doesn't work". What went wrong?
This works example works fine. To use the object (uncomment the lines) make sure you set the `DisplayMember` property, note that I am not having to cast because I use that property.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        List<string> x = new List<string>();
        x.Add("A");
        x.Add("B");
        x.Add("C");
        x.Add("D");
        x.Add("B");


        List<Client> z = new List<Client>();
        z.Add(new Client() { Name = "A" });
        z.Add(new Client() { Name = "B" });
        z.Add(new Client() { Name = "C" });

        comboBox.Items.AddRange(x.ToArray());

        //comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        //listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        //comboBox.Items.AddRange(z.ToArray());


    }

    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(comboBox.SelectedItem);
    }
}


public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ante I think the issue comes from comboBox.SelectedItem, this returns an Object and in your case that Object happens to be a System.Data.DataRowView.  I think you'll need to cast the combobox.selectedItem to a value.  I'm a VB guy so not sure the syntax for C# but in VB we'd do something like this:

```
DirectCast(combobox.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Foo
```

with foo being what ever value you want to pass to the listbox.

Another option that might work, if your intention is to include the value of the combo box in the listbox is to use:

```
combobox.selectedvalue
```

this returns and Object but it's actually the object that is being displayed in the combobox weather it be a string, int, etc.  Not sure if that helps but I've had to do something very similar to this in the past and that's the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

The selected item of the combobox is a DataRowView, and the listbox is calling `DataRowView.ToString()` to work out what to display.

You can either

1. Cast the `object` return value of `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to `DataRowView`, and add the value of the column you want to display. (i.e. `listbox.Items.Add(((DataRowView)combobox.SelectedItem).FieldName);`
2. Set the "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" values of the listbox, so the listbox doesn't just use `ToString()` any more.  This is probably something you've already done for your comboxbox, otherwise it would also be displaying "System.Data.DataRowView".

Comment: tnx for help, second one solved the problem but slugster mentioned that first.. so i have to give him "nike sign"

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get at the (untyped) row:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) combobox.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = drv.Row;
```

After that it depends on what colum you need, if you know the Column name:

```
object value = row["Column"];
listbox.Items.Add(value);
```